# Error when I try to deserialize an object

Tags: java, file, deserialization

I am coding using GitHub with my friend, and when we update the main class, the IDE provides us the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.InvalidClassException: Packages.contoCorrente; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -433050874178120905, local class serialVersionUID = -5213999116280532749
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:689)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1958)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1827)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2115)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1646)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:464)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:928)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1160)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2271)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2142)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1646)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:464)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
at ObjectWrite.main(ObjectWrite.java:31)
```

To fix the problem, I always delete the main object file, so it can rebuild it. I am also attaching the part of code that deals with deserialization, in the hope that someone will help me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ArrayList<contoCorrente> contiCorrentiArray;
        File file = new File("contiCorrenti");
        if (file.exists()) {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream fileObjIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

            //noinspection unchecked
            contiCorrentiArray = (ArrayList<contoCorrente>) fileObjIn.readObject();


            fileObjIn.close();
            fileIn.close();
        } else {
            contiCorrentiArray = new ArrayList<>();
        }

    System.out.println("Numero Conti Presenti: " + contiCorrentiArray.size() + "\n");
```

Comment: add your class  `contoCorrente`. By the way, to follow naming conventions it should be  `ContoCorrente`

Answer (score 1):

Do you and your Partner have the same  serialVersionUID?

If not, you both should define it, so it doesn't get calculated automatically.

From the docs:

> If a serializable class does not explicitly declare a
>   serialVersionUID, then the serialization runtime will calculate a
>   default serialVersionUID value for that class based on various aspects
>   of the class, as described in the Java(TM) Object Serialization
>   Specification. However, it is strongly recommended that all
>   serializable classes explicitly declare serialVersionUID values, since
>   the default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class
>   details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can
>   thus result in unexpected InvalidClassExceptions during
>   deserialization. Therefore, to guarantee a consistent serialVersionUID
>   value across different java compiler implementations, a serializable
>   class must declare an explicit serialVersionUID value. It is also
>   strongly advised that explicit serialVersionUID declarations use the
>   private modifier where possible, since such declarations apply only to
>   the immediately declaring class--serialVersionUID fields are not
>   useful as inherited members. Array classes cannot declare an explicit
>   serialVersionUID, so they always have the default computed value, but
>   the requirement for matching serialVersionUID values is waived for
>   array classes. `

Comment: where can we define it? Because we are using serialization recently and we don't know how to move...

Comment: Add a line like     `private static final long serialVersionUID = -1662022300670224623L;` in class `conteCorrente` .

Comment: Exactly as Turo said.